# asp classic sql server 2005 can't connect

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I am trying to connect to a 2005 sql server and pull information from it on asp classic. I already made a java application and i was able to pull information from it using these variables.

```
//SQL Server Values
String userName = "sa";
String password = "Passw0rd";
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://DLI9200;instanceName=SQLExpress;databaseName=DLIDEV";
```

and this is my class

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

I can connect fine with this i am also using the authorization.dll and the sqljdbc4.jar for my java portion of the project.

For my asp-classic side i am using this as my connection string.

```
<%
ConnString ="Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=DLI9200\SQLEXPRESS; Database=DLIDEV; User Id=sa; Password=Passw0rd;"
%>
```

I thought this would work but it doesn't seem to be loading anything.I put the pages on tomcat and the pages goes load just nothing is showing up at all on IE. But I am not getting any error from any of the pages, also in case it helps the sql server and the asp pages are on the same machine. Any help or advice would be greatly helped and appreciated.

Comment: There could be an error but it may just not be getting caught. Does Java have a try-catch type block you could define to catch any exceptions when it attempts to get data?

Comment: You're running classic ASP pages in Tomcat? Is that possible really?

Comment: I don't know on the Tomcat part but it does load the pages. Why is there another way of loading the pages?

Comment: No the java part is fine, I can access my db with the java variables i set i am just wondering if i properly converted that to asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit - You can't run classic ASP on Tomcat, you need IIS (or IIS Express).  Maybe Tomcat is serving your pages as if they are flat HTML, but it won't do anything with the server side code.

Your conn string looks fine, but here are two things to try.

First, replace SQLOLEDB with SQLNCLI. (SQLNCLI10 if you're using MSSQL 2008, or SQLNCLI11 if MSSQL 2012)

Second - if you want to stick with SQLOLEDB, try using `Initial Catalog=DLIDEV` (instead of `Database=DLIDEV`)

Comment: Hmm that would explain why i can see the flat html and no errors. is it possible to run both Tomcat and IIS on the same computer? and is there a guide you can suggest for setting up IIS for classic asp?And is there another option to use besides SQLOLEDDB?

Comment: And is SQLOLEDB okay for MSSQL 2005? or should i use something else?

Comment: SQLOLEDB should work for any version.  Native Client (SQLNCLI) first appeared with 2005, later versions of MSSQL come with later versions of Native Client, which is why you add the 10 or the 11.  This link might help. http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Here's what Microsoft have to say about IIS/Classic ASP - http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8
You can have Tomcat and IIS running at the same time using different ports.  If your aim is to have java and asp on the same website it might be tricky to implement.  I've never tried this myself - but here are the instructions - http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Comment: I downloaded IIS express 7.5 , but i can't seem to find the IIS manager to start up or setup the pages for the webserver is it hidden somewhere in the IIS 7.5 express folder?

Comment: IIS Express is a cut down version which doesn't come with IIS manager.  I think express does support Classic ASP by default though.  What version of Windows are you using?  Pro versions ship with IIS

Comment: stuck programming on windows xp at the moment i check and it seems i need the cd to install the real version of IIS. I guess i am going to have to do that and hope it doesn't interfer with express

Comment: You shouldn't need the cd if it's xp pro, you should be able to activate it through Control Panel -> add/remove components.  If it's xp home then IIS isn't included.  As a last resort look at Active Local Pages - which will render ASP code client side (through Internet Explorer only) http://www.activelocalpages.com/

Comment: Is it tablet edition xp so i think i would need it sadly. I will have to try that website, I can't understand how to get asp classic to work with iis 7.5 express without a gui

Comment: I'd be surprised if express needed any extra configuration to serve a file with the .asp extension.  It's designed for development, unlike full IIS which is a production webserver where everything is locked down by default. Two more links for you. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx